# PHP mb_strpos not recognizing copyright symbol

Tags: php, strpos, mbstring

I am trying to use the mb_strpos PHP function to search for the © symbol on certain webpages.

```
       $pagecontent = file_get_contents($website_url);

        if (mb_strpos($pagecontent, $string_to_find) === false) {

                // String / Content NOT found on page (FAIL)
                return false;

        } else {

                // String / Content FOUND on page (SUCCESS)
                return true;
        }
```

I would pass the ***$website_url*** and ***$string_to_find*** "Copyright ©" variables to the function however it returns false, even though I know the © is present in the web page. If I remove the © character from the string, then it returns true.. so im guessing there is an issue with PHP trying to find © symbols?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: is the website displaying the copyright symbol or the html entity `&copy;` that represents the copyright symbol? You can tell by viewing the source.

Comment: It's also likely that a lot of websites use `&copy;` instead of `©`.

Comment: There may also be character encoding issues.

Comment: Hi it's not using &copy; the source just shows the symbol as is. Both my php script and the web page itself are both UTF8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `mb_strpos` I assume you set the encoding with `mb_internal_encoding`? Because otherwise you could just use `strpos`.

So, what is the encoding of the website? And what is your "internal encoding"? I bet they don't match.

E.g. if the website is encoded in UTF-8, you can use

```
mb_strpos($pagecontent, $string_to_find, 0, "utf-8")
```

Furthermore, booleans are values, so you can simplify your code to

```
$pagecontent = file_get_contents($website_url);
return (mb_strpos($pagecontent, $string_to_find) !== false);
```

The full solution would be:

```
$pagecontent = file_get_contents($website_url);
return (mb_strpos($pagecontent, $string_to_find, 0, "utf-8") !== false);
```

assuming the website is using UTF-8. Also, you have to make sure that the $string_to_find has the same encoding. If you placed the Copyright symbol as a string literal into your code (as `"©"`), your source files should be UTF-8 encoded as well. In PHP, strings are just byte streams internally.

---

Other possibility (I just read the comments above): the website contains a `&copy;` HTML entity. In that case, you'd have to search for `&copy;` instead.